# @metamask/detect-provider is not importing

Tags: javascript, import, metamask

I am trying to import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider'.

When inspecting my website with live server open, I get a line saying

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@metamask/detect-provider". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I have installed using npm install @metamask/detect-provider.

My package.json shows "@metamask/detect-provider": "^1.2.0",

It shows up in my node_modules.

In my index.html file, I include this:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@metamask/detect-provider/dist/detect-provider.min.js"></script>`

I am not sure what I have done wrong. If there is any other code I need to show please let me know what to show.

Comment: Did you figure it out yet? I'm stumped so far

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar error, I tried `npm audit fix --force` (twice) and it resolved the issue.